# which function takes no constant parameters similar to system(constant char) in linux

Tags: c, linux

i want to execute script cmd in the c program so the function SYSTEM(CONST  CHAR ) does  it  but  i want to use this function with 3 different parameters writing once    . can anybody help me  , is there any function of that kind.

Comment: I think you haven't understood the purpose of `const` parameters. `const char *` means that `system` doesn't overwrite its argument internally.

Comment: yes, i understood as it is CONST  , but i want it not to be const but just a (char *) is there any function that   supports this  facility  of taking input  and  functions as system()    plz  try to help me

Answer (score 1):

If I guessed it right you want to call a cmd using system() like function with multiple arguments, if yes then you can do following

```
char cmd[SIZE];
snprintf(cmd, <SIZE>, "<cmd> %d %f %c" argument1, argument2, argument3);
system(cmd);
```

also you can customize the snprintf to suite your needs and your arguments.

[EDIT] Used snprintf instead of sprintf [/EDIT]

Comment: @larsmans, I updated the recommendation for snprintf instead of sprintf. Happy now?

Comment: but system() does not takes variable as parameter